# Object in Vector can't be converted to int

Tags: java, vector

I have a function `fillOval(int x, int y, int xSize, int ySize)` and an array with 4 `Vectors` which are created with my `new2DVector` method.

However, when I try to do:

```
for(Vector v : punkte) {
    screen.fillOval(v.get(0), v.get(1), 60,60);
}
```

I get an error message that v.get(0) and v.get(1) are objects and can't be converted to int.

Then I tried adding an identifier like so:

```
public Vector<int> new2DVector(int x, int y) { //<int> unexpected type error. required: reference
    Vector v = new Vector(2);
    v.add(x);
    v.add(y);
    return v;
}
```

But the error is still present.
What am I doing wrong here? It doesn't work like this: `Vector<int> v = new Vector(2);` either.

Comment: You're getting raw-type warnings for a reason. You need `Vector<Integer>` and should read a tutorial on Java generics.

Comment: `int` cannot be used as a generic. You'll need to box it. i.e. `Vector<Integer>`

Comment: I think you should create Vector2d rather than using generic version here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use primitive type `int` as generic type. Please use `Integer` instead.

Answer (score 0):

the class Vector is a class generic, java not accept primitive types in class generics.

you can use a reference type as Integer.
...
public Vector new2D Vector(int x, int y)
...

Observation: Vector is considered a obsolet class, denpeding on your need look for a better alternative.

sorry my english.